# Where is yarn application history stored?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have run some Map Reduce applications. The application histories show up in the YARN UI web page http://localhost:8088/cluster

And Application Timeline Server is not enabled, because of the following config

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.timeline-service.enabled</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <source>yarn-default.xml</source>
</property>
```

**So I want to know where are these application histories stored?**

Answer (score 1):

`yarn.nodemanager.log-dirs` stores the container log files on each individual nodemanagers local disk. If you have log aggregation enabled  by `yarn.log-aggregation-enable`, then those logs will be aggregated to an HDFS location set by `yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir`